# How do i retrieve both the key and the value from a json object?

Tags: sql, json, mariadb

I am trying to retrieve both parts of a JSON object through a stored procedure, for example from {bob:ben, 3:sue, James:cat} I want to get each part of the pair separately using sql. So it would be like this

```
col1 | col2
bob  | ben
3    | sue
James| cat
```

How do i do this?

Comment: SQL requires all values in the same column to have the same type (`string`, `number`, etc). How do you intend to handle cases where values have different types?

Comment: I was storing them as a varchar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy to achieve by using some of these functions `JSON_KEYS`, `JSON_EXTRACT` and `JSON_CONCAT`.

For example, you could create table iterating this select:

```
set @json = '{"bob:ben", "3":"sue", "James":"cat"}';
set @indx = 0;
set @keys = JSON_KEYS(@json);
select JSON_EXTRACT(@keys, CONCAT("$[", @indx, "]")) as colum1, 
        JSON_EXTRACT(@json,CONCAT("$.", JSON_EXTRACT(@keys, CONCAT("$[", @indx, "]")))) as colum2;
```

For further information you have all the JSON mariadb function in this link:

[MARIADB JSON FUNCTIONS](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/json_keys/)

Comment: I have the JSON called as a paramater in the stored procedure how do i set the @json to it?